# Trace Bug which happends only sometimes in CI

Tags: python, debugging, trace

I have a strange bug in python code which only happens sometimes in CI.

We can't reproduce it.

Where is the test code:

```
response=self.admin_client.post(url, post)
self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, response)
```

Sometimes we get a 302 which happens since the form gets saved.

My idea to debug this:

```
with some_magic_trace.trace() as trace:
    response=self.admin_client.post(url, post)
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, trace)
```

The trace should contain the python lines (filename, line offset, line as string) executed by the interpreter.

How to implement `some_magic_trace.trace()`?

Comment: Isn't the [programmatic interface](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/trace.html#programmatic-interface) of python's standard trace module enough for this task? Why is the interpreter normal traceback insufficient?

Comment: @StefanoM the programmatic interface could help. Thank you for this hint. To the next question, why the normal interpreter traceback is not enough: I method returns a value which I don't expect. That's all I know up to now. I want to know what has happened before the value was returned. I can't see this in a traceback. Normally you would use a debugger in this case. But the error only shows up in the continuous integration environment. Not elsewhere :-(

Answer (score 8):

The [trace](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/trace.html#module-trace) module gives you a very simple solution (different from what you are asking for, but simple enough to have a try.)

```
from trace import Trace

tracer = Trace()
response = tracer.runfunc(self.admin_client.post, url, post)
self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, response)
```

A more complex solution that entails creating a context manager that saves the trace and prints it only on exceptions, requires the use of [sys.settrace](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html?highlight=settrace#sys.settrace).
Just a template for your own implementation could be:

```
class MyTracer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.trace = None

    def newscope(self, frame, event, arg):
        ## real work should be done here, just minimal example
        self.trace.append((frame, event, arg))
        return None

    def pprint(self):
        ## real pretty printing of trace info should be done here
        print(self.trace)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.trace = []
        sys.settrace(self.newscope)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.settrace(None)
        if exc_type is not None:
            self.pprint()
            ## print some info gathered from exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb
```

Then you can:

```
with MyTracer():
    response=self.admin_client.post(url, post)
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, response)
```

The idea is that a MyTracer instance has a tracer method `newscope` that saves some useful info in `self.trace`. On an abnormal exit from the context the `pprint` method is called; on a normal exit the trace info is discarded.

Most of the work has to be done in the tracing method `newscope`.
Some concrete examples of tracing functions can be found [here](https://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html).

Comment: instead use `with MyTracer() as tracer:` since your implementation only prints the data if there was an error but the issues in the question isn't raising an error, by keeping it as `tracer` you can then access `tracer.trace` and get better information about it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen my understanding is that a trace is wanted only when `self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, response)` raises an exception, and that this is a rather unusual situation.  The idea is to "buffer" the trace info in the `MyTracer` object, and use the exception as trigger to print out the collected data. In most of the cases you just discard it. Of course you have the flexibility to choose what exceptions trigger the printing of the collected data.

Comment: I am only referring to the example use, even if `printff` is never called by using `with MyTracer() as tracer` the program will still have access to recorded frames in `tracer.trace`, directed more towards anyone using your implementation.  Very model answer!

Answer (score 5):

**Note: `Stefano M`'s solution is the correct answer since fits perfectly with StackOverflow standards**

For those unfamiliar with working with Frame/traceback objects I have provided a working `Tracker` class **built from `Stefano M`'s `MyTracer` template**:

```
import sys,traceback

def printf(*stuff,sep=" ",end="\n",file=sys.stdout):
    file.write(sep.join(stuff)+end)#for backward compatability with python2

class Tracker:
    def __init__(self,out_file = sys.stdout):
        assert out_file.writable(),"need to open a file for writing"
        self.out = out_file
        self.last_frame = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_trace = sys.gettrace()
        sys.settrace(self.newscope)

    def __exit__(self,etype,value,tb):
        sys.settrace(self.old_trace)
        self.finish_previous()
        if tb:
            traceback.printf_exception(etype,value,tb,file=self.out)
        else:
            printf("exit status normal",file=self.out)


    def newscope(self,f,e,ar):
        self.finish_previous(f)

        global_vars = f.f_globals
        for name,module in sys.modules.items():
            if global_vars is vars(module):
                file_name = name
                break
        else:
            file_name = "??"
            module = None

        printf(self._format_module(file_name,f.f_lineno),file=self.out)

        if module:
            printf(self._read_line_of_file(module,f.f_lineno),file=self.out)


    @staticmethod
    def _format_module(file_name,line):
        return "{}, line:{}".format(file_name,line)

    @staticmethod
    def _read_line_of_file(module,line):
        try:
            with open(module.__file__,"r") as FILE:
                line = list(FILE)[line]
                return line
        except Exception as e:
            return "ERROR WHEN READING FILE: %r"%e

    @staticmethod
    def _local_vars(frame):
        return "locals:\n    "+"\n    ".join("{} = {!r}".format(*pair) for pair in frame.f_locals.items())

    def finish_previous(self,new_frame=None):
        if self.last_frame:
            printf(self._local_vars(self.last_frame),end="\n\n\n",file=self.out)
        self.last_frame = new_frame
```

Then it can be used like this for displaying output to standard output:

```
with Tracker():
    response=self.admin_client.post(url, post)
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, trace)
```

or to send output to a file you can do this:

```
with open("log.txt","w") as f, Tracker(f):
    response=self.admin_client.post(url, post)
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, trace)
```

hope that can give you immediate results but you would still be much better off to implement the template  by **Stefano M** yourself since the information you are looking for is likely different then what I would want displayed.

Answer (score 1):

To use `trace.Trace` with the `with` context instead of `Trace.runfunc` you can use:

```
import trace

class ContextTrace(trace.Trace):
    def __enter__(self):
        if not self.donothing:
            sys.settrace(self.globaltrace)
        return self

    def __exit__(self,*others):
        if not self.donothing:
            sys.settrace(None)
```